# SQL Server deleted records even though there was an error in the subquery which located in where clause with IN tag

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

As you see from these images, the `ROSHEADERID` column is invalid and when I execute the first one it returns a meaningful message. But when I use this query in where clause as a subquery. It executes and deletes all of the records without warning or aborting the operation.

How can this be ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subquery has access to columns in outer query, thus column `ROSHEADERID` you ask for is effectively taken from `EXM_REVIEWOFSYSTEMS` (not from `EXM_REVIEWOFSYSTEMSHEADER`), thus deleting all records in outer table.

This should clarify a bit on what's going on behind the scenes:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/623c7/3

More information here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187638(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Use Alias Names for tables to avoid conflict:

```
BEGIN TRAN
   DELETE   FROM EXM_REVIEWOFSYSTEMS
   WHERE    ROSHEADERID IN ( SELECT rsh.ROSHEADERID
                             FROM   EXM_REVIEWOFSYSTEMSHEADER rsh
                             WHERE  rsh.PATIENTID = '' )
   ROLLBACK TRAN
```

Comment: You are right. I thought the subquery itself in execution plan then the outer. But in execution plan the first thing is parsing the statement.